# Determine which App Store a user downloaded the app from (region-wise)

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there a way to determine which App Store (US, UK, etc) a user downloaded my app from? I need to display different things in the app based on which store the app was downloaded in.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is problably a better way of doing that, depending on what the purpose is and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Legal reasons. If a user downloads an app from the UK App Store but then travels to the US, I still need it to behave as if they were in the UK.

Comment: Are you sure? It is not really a problem bying in the UK App stroe from the US or Germany etc.

Comment: I can't really say exactly why it matters but it matters, trust me. I need to know which app store the user downloaded the app from.

Comment: As I do not have an answer to your question literally, I'd suggest to geht the user's location when the app is started for the first time. If that is refused by the user then let him choose a country.

Comment: That might be my only option. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: I'd rather had a better answer for you.

Comment: I would suggest asking the user for his region first thing when they launch the app.

Comment: Extending @LeoNatan's suggestion, when you ask the user for their region, you can use their current locale to set a sensible default.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is to release multiple versions of your app and set store availability for each one through iTunesConnect - this still isn't guaranteed as there is nothing you can do to prevent people setting up iTunes accounts in another country, but I suspect most people use their "local" store.